# types of cells in a pharyngeal specimen

Tags: microbiology, cell-culture

I would like to ask what type of cells should someone expect in a pharyngeal smear, in a person, who is infected with a viral infection. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a medical question rather than one primarily about biology. This means it is not on-topic for this site. While this might be a better fit for [MedicalSciences.SE], please don't repost (instead request migration). Please consult the [tour], [ask], and other [help] pages for more information.  Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

The tissue in the pharynx include:

[Stratified squamous epithelium & mucus-producing glands.](https://opentextbc.ca/anatomyandphysiology/chapter/23-3-the-mouth-pharynx-and-esophagus/)

However other cells that could be found would be other types of bacterial, is this what you're referencing?

Commonly scientists start with a gram stain to determine the classify the bacteria.

Gram+ bacteria have cell walls composed of **thick** layers of peptidoglycan. Gram+ cells stain purple when. Gram- bacteria have cell walls with a **thin** layer of peptidoglycan. Gram- bacteria stain pink.

The microbiome of a human consists of 100,000 billion bacteria. Therefore there are many types. E.g. [Prevotella](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4411333/) has been shown to be the most common type of bacteria in the human pharynx.

In a pharyngeal smear you would expect to find Stratified squamous epithelium, mucus-producing glands, bacteria and if a virus is present. Viral particles. This can be determined by RNA or DNA analysis.

E.g. COVID-19 is an RNA virus. If PCR analysis was completed on a sample obtained from a pharyngeal smear then we could confirm the presence of the aforementioned mammalian cells, bacteria and viral genetic material.

Comment: should someone expect lymphocytes?

Comment: @Marilu, lymphocytes continuously circulate between the lymph and blood until they encounter a foreign antigen. It would be possible, but it's usually not the aim of a pharyngeal smear. A blood test would provide better results to identify how 'hard' the immune system to working.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help Marilu.